# Using Spring Framework from source code

Tags: java, spring

I would like to build Spring framework (or at least one of its subcomponents) locally in order to add more logging into the private code that I can not access from my program.

What would be the steps to build it and to use it in my program, instead of spring dependency downloaded from maven?

Comment: Have you tried to set your logging-config to DEBUG/TRACE for the spring component you are interested in?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking at spring source code and I do not have logging where I need it.

Comment: You should be more specific on: what component do you want to change and what you already tried... to get (better) answers

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Building-from-source

Comment: I have spring-framework library and I need to add more logging to spring-websocket classes. I did not tried anything because I can not find how to build locally and replace the dependency.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework#building-from-source would be the up to date link

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to debug (either locally or remotely), set breakpoints and inspect the surroundings from your IDE?

Comment: I am investigating a compled deadlock problem - I learnt how to kill the websocket server with some super slow client :) So I need to see the dynamics in logs.

Comment: @kryger also please note that not errors are wrong vairable contents. Websocket is a highly concurrent environment, complete with synchronized blocks, and you sometimes need to let this just run and experience concurrency kind of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the relevant instructions were found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework#building-from-source. These are sufficient to get local spring running. Note the separate notes for e.g. intellij idea!

Once local maven repo is enabled in build.gradle as such:

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
}
```

and correct dependences are set for the Spring version, project will pick up jars that were compiled locally.